# .htaccess redirect sub directory access attempts back to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to protect folders such as `/css` and `/js` from listing directory contents to snoopers. Perhaps I could do this via PHP, but I need to use `.htaccess`.

Desired:

Anyone browsing to `http://example.com/css` should not see a listing of files, but is immediately redirected back to `http://example.com`.

I have tried several variations on the following, but cannot seem to get it right:

.htaccess inside each private folder:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Redirect 301 /. http://example.com
```

or, in the webroot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

---

Note: I already have an .htaccess file in the webroot, which any additional mod_rewrite commands would need to accomodate:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /dev/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `/css/.htacces` with this line:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/
Options -Indexes
```

Do same in `/js/.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks, that does suppress the directory listing, however it does not redirect user back to root, which is what I also need to do.

Comment: No, that made a bit of a mess. The index page loaded (correct) but was missing all css and images..., and the address bar still said `http://mydomain.com/css`. Perhaps it loaded the index page from inside the css folder, rather than redirecting back to webroot and loading index.php from there...?

Comment: Yessir, your latest update did the trick. Well done, and thanks!